# Bash script results in different output when running from a cron job

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm puzzled by this problem I'm having on Ubuntu 20.04 where cron is able to run a bash script but the overall outcome is different then when using the shell command.
I've look through all questions I could in here and on Google but couldn't find anyone that had the same problem.

Background:
I'm using Pushgateway to store metrics I'm generating through a bash script, and afterwards it's being imported automatically to Prometheus.
The end goal is to export a list of running processes, their CPU%, Mem% etc, similar to `top` command.

This is the bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
z=$(top -n 1 -bi)
while read -r z
do
   var=$var$(awk 'FNR>7{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$12"\", pid=\""$1"\"}", $9z} FNR>7{print "memory_usage{process=\""$12"\", pid=\""$1"\"}", $10z}')
done <<< "$z"
curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "$var
" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

I used to have a version that used `ps aux` but then I found out that it only shows the average CPU% per process.

As you can see, the command I'm running is `top -n 1 -bi` which gives me a snapshot of active processes and their metrcis.
I'm using `awk` to format the data, and `FNR>7` because I need to ignore the first 7 lines which is the summery presented by `top`.

The bash scrip is registered on /bin, /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin.

When checking http://localhost:9091/metrics, which is supposed to show me the information gathered, I'm getting this some of information when running the scrip using shell:

```
cpu_usage{instance="machine",job="top",pid="114468",process="php-fpm74"} 17.6
cpu_usage{instance="machine",job="top",pid="114483",process="php-fpm74"} 11.8
cpu_usage{instance="machine",job="top",pid="126305",process="ffmpeg"} 64.7
```

And this is the same information when cron is running the same script:

```
cpu_usage{instance="machine",job="top",pid="114483",process="php-fpm+"} 5
cpu_usage{instance="machine",job="top",pid="126305",process="ffmpeg"} 60
cpu_usage{instance="machine",job="top",pid="128777",process="php"} 15
```

So, for some reason, when I run it from cron it cuts the process name after 7 places.
I initially though it was related to the FNR>7 but even after changing it to 8 or 9 (and using `exec bash` to re-register the command) it gives the same results, also when I run it manually it works just fine.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: It is `top` that truncate the command name to fit the terminal number of columns. It does not happened with interactive CLI as `top` formats its output considering your current terminal width due to `-b` and a launch from a shell interpreter. When top is launched from a shell command line spawn from `crond`,  it then requires `-w` to have an output width, otherwise it will default to `COLMUMNS=80`. Add `-w 160` to the `top` command line in your script, it should fix it.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much you fixed my problem completely!!!